# onTouchEvent call various time

Tags: android

This is my MainActivity for a special gesture I'm using in my app (a double L : with one finger who swipe **up to bottom** and **bottom to left** + the other finger who swipe **up to bottom** and **bottom to right** at the same time)

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean movingDownL = false;
boolean movingDownR = false;
boolean movingLeft = false;
boolean movingRight = false;

boolean movingSuccessL = false;
boolean movingSuccessR = false;

// Deviation in pixels from the route (error value)
int downInaccuracy = 30; // Down
int lnrInaccuracy = 10; // Left and Right

// Minimum distance to apply move (300 px in down and 100 to the left/right)
int downMinDistance = 300;
int lnrMinDistance = 50;

Point oldCoordsL = new Point(0, 0); // Old coordinates left
Point oldCoordsR = new Point(0, 0); // Old coordinates right
Point startPointL = new Point(0, 0);
Point startPointR = new Point(0, 0);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int pIndexL = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(0));
    int pIndexR = 0;

    // If we have more than 1 touch read second finger index
    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) pIndexR = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(1));

    // Check if we do not mistake when read fingers id
    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1 && event.getX(pIndexL) > event.getX(pIndexR)) {
        int tmp = pIndexR;
        pIndexR = pIndexL;
        pIndexL = tmp;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            movingDownL = true; // Start moving fingers
            movingDownR = true;
            movingSuccessL = false;
            movingSuccessR = false;

            // Get start point left and right if we need
            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                startPointR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
                oldCoordsR = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexR), (int) event.getY(pIndexR));
            }

            startPointL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
            oldCoordsL = new Point((int) event.getX(pIndexL), (int) event.getY(pIndexL));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Add right finger handler
            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                if(!movingDownR) {
                    // Check if we still moving to down
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) < downInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) break;
                    // Start moving to the right
                    if(Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                            oldCoordsR.x > event.getX(pIndexR) && !movingRight) {
                        movingRight = true;
                        startPointR = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR)));
                    }
                }else {
                    if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.x - event.getX(pIndexR)) > downInaccuracy ||
                            oldCoordsR.y < event.getY(pIndexR)) {
                        movingDownR = false;
                        break;
                    } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                            new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= downMinDistance){
                        // Start moving to the left/right
                        movingDownR = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Left finger handler by default even if we got only one touch
            // Check if we need move to any side
            if(!movingDownL) {
                // Check if we still moving to down
                if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) < downInaccuracy &&
                        oldCoordsL.y < event.getY(pIndexL)) break;
                // Start moving to the left
                if(Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) < lnrInaccuracy &&
                        oldCoordsL.x < event.getX(pIndexL) && !movingLeft) {
                    movingLeft = true;
                    startPointL = new Point(new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL)));
                }
            }else {
                if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.x - event.getX(pIndexL)) > downInaccuracy ||
                        oldCoordsL.y > event.getY(pIndexL)) {
                    movingDownL = false;
                    break;
                } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                        new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= downMinDistance){
                    // Start moving to the left/right
                    movingDownL = false;
                }
            }

            // Left move handler
            if(movingLeft) {
                if (Math.abs(oldCoordsL.y - event.getY(pIndexL)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                        oldCoordsL.x > event.getX(pIndexL)) {
                    movingLeft = false;
                    break;
                } else if(findDistance(startPointL,
                        new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                    movingLeft = false;
                    movingSuccessL = true; // L from left finger is OK
                }
            }

            // Right move handler
            if(movingRight) {
                if (Math.abs(oldCoordsR.y - event.getY(pIndexR)) > lnrInaccuracy ||
                        oldCoordsR.x < event.getX(pIndexR)) {
                    movingRight = false;
                    break;
                } else if(findDistance(startPointR,
                        new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR))) >= lnrMinDistance) {
                    movingRight = false;
                    movingSuccessR = true; // L from right finger is OK
                }
            }

            if(movingSuccessL && movingSuccessR) {
                Log.d("debug, "Yeah, it's look like double L");
            } else if(movingSuccessL) Log.d("debug, "Yeah, it's look like L");

            oldCoordsL = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexL), (int)event.getY(pIndexL));
            oldCoordsR = new Point((int)event.getX(pIndexR), (int)event.getY(pIndexR));

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            movingDownL = false;
            movingDownR = false;
            movingLeft = false;
            movingRight = false;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private double findDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
```

}

The problem is in the debug console : I have various time the "Yeah, it's look like double L". I would like to have just one when I make the double L.
Maybe I have to put a timer. I don't know how I have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make it so you don't actually say "double L" until the touch up that ends the move.  Just store wether or not you already saw a double L and check that variable on the touch up.  ANd remember to clear that variable out on a touch down.